# Intellij doesn't create main files ans resource in create project

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm using the latest version on `Intellij` for programing and developing Android. After installing and tring to create project for first time, Intellij doesn't create a main files/folders and manifest and I don't have them in the project. Please see screen shot:

[image]

I tried to do `file - invalidate caches/restart` and tried to define the Android SDK again, but my problem doesn't resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you follow all this steps:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-a-gradle-android-project.html